# Simultaneous zero set of two equations in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Can we have positive reals $x,y,z$ with
$$  x^{\left( y^z \right)}  =   y^{\left( z^x \right)}  =  z^{\left( x^y \right)}      $$ in cyclic permutation, other than the line $x=y=z$?

I put this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493739/this-is-stupid-but-i-have-a-bad-cold-with-cough and one poor guy has been hacking away at it. I still have no idea.

I would love to see some representation of the supposed surface $$  x^{\left( y^z \right)}  =   y^{\left( z^x \right)},      $$ which I feel really ought to be some ugly variant of the helicoid around the line $x=y=z$.

EDIT, Thursday:  Is it true that the gradient of $$ \color{magenta}{ h(x,y,z) = x^{\left( y^z \right)}  -   y^{\left( z^x \right)}},      $$ is defined and a nonzero vector along the line, say, at the point $x=y=z=t$ for positive real $t?$ If so, the surface is orthogonal to that at the line...Further, if you switch to one of the other pairs as a difference, I expect the gradient vector to be rotated by $120^\circ;$ this gives a pretty good reason for there being no other points on all three such surfaces near the known line.

Comment: Dear @Will Jagy: I removed the deprecated tag 'geometry' from this question. I do not know what to replace it with. Please feel free to add a more specific alternative tag.

Comment: I believe you have put your finger on the problem. My entire life is deprecated.

Comment: Re: gradient. I suppose it is defined along the line and is indeed rotated when switching pairs. The gradient appears to be:  `-(t^(t + t^t + 1)*log(t)^2 - t^(t + t^t))/t , (t^(t + t^t + 1)*log(t) - t^(t + t^t))/t , t^(t + t^t)*log(t)^2 - t^(t + t^t)*log(t)`

Comment: A better parametrization is: `y = exp(-LambertW(-z^(1-x)*ln(x))/z)`

Comment: @joro, is this last one a parametrization for a difference of two out of three, as in your "answer"

Comment: Will, yes it is just for two of them. For the third we are looking for solutions to a single equation in x,y right after EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 30):

The following Maple-produced animation suggests that there isn't any other solution.  The three curves (for each value of $x$) are $x^{y^z}=y^{z^x}$ (red), $y^{z^x}=z^{x^y}$ (blue) and $z^{x^y}=x^{y^z}$ (cyan).  The one point in each frame where all three intersect is, of course, $x=y=z$.  There don't appear to be any other triple intersections.

[image]

Comment: Right, and there is one behavior change at $1$ and another at $2$

Comment: This is a mesmerizing animation, all the more beautiful because it perfectly illustrates a mathematical point. Thanks, Robert!

Answer (score 8):

Maple found closed form for $z$ and parametrization over $\mathbb{C}$
for $x^{(y^z)}=y^{(z^x)}$:

$$ z= {{\rm e}^{ \left( -x{\it LambertW} \left( -\ln  \left( y \right) { {\rm e}^{\ln  \left( {\frac {\ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( y \right) }} \right) {x}^{-1}}}{x}^{-1} \right) +\ln  \left( {\frac { \ln  \left( x \right) }{\ln  \left( y \right) }} \right)  \right) {x}^ {-1}}} \qquad (1) $$

**EDIT**

Substituting $z$ in the other equation and solving, we are looking
for positive real solutions of

```
x^exp(ln(y)*exp((-x*LambertW(-ln(y)/x*exp(ln(ln(x)/ln(y))/x))+ln(ln(x)/ln(y)))/x))-exp((-x*LambertW(-ln(y)/x*exp(ln(ln(x)/ln(y))/x))+ln(ln(x)/ln(y)))/x)^(x^y)
```

Complex solutions exist, e.g.

```
x1= (4.039760831390928810096443230122786460497 - 3.794516696260006267408154939005426227609j)
y1= (2.764005926356850384451036006794311106205 + 0.0j)
z1= (1.273990994985239416952018723391988170796 + 0.2830754921068781180566923204291057573632j)
```

Things get complicated by the fact that with the principal branches
of $W$ and $\log$ $(1)$ need not be real and might have imaginary part.

Here is a plot of $(1)$ taking the principal branches and the real
part. The plot is wrong because it has some artifacts caused by 
imaginary part.

Will try to make correct plot if I have the time.

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about solutions over C. It would be informative to have the picture with $x,y > 1,$ where perhaps there is just one branch of everything.

Comment: In particular, this plot contains the line $x=1, y=1$ with no bound on $z.$ So maybe $x > 1.1, y > 1.1$

Comment: @Will will make another picture. (2,5) has imaginary part, so branches still cause trouble...

Comment: Huh. Oh, well. I certainly never expected to see any sort of formulaic solution for one of these.

Comment: @WillJagy me too. Get numerical support over C for the paramatrization.

Comment: @WillJagy edited the question with complex solutions and equation for the full problem.

Comment: @WillJagy here is a plot from 1.1 to 9 (again wrong, maybe about half of it is correct): http://s9.postimg.org/472q3udr3/will2.jpg

Comment: Another plot from 2 to 9 using root finding: http://s7.postimg.org/fdovi58kb/will4.png

Comment: Joro, one thing would help me, for behavior near the line $x=y=z.$ Is it true that the gradient of $$ h(x,y,z) = x^{\left( y^z \right)}  -   y^{\left( z^x \right)},      $$ is defined and a nonzero vector along the line, say, at the point $x=y=z=t$ for positive real $t?$ If so, the surface is orthogonal to that at the line...Further, if you switch to one of the other pairs as a difference, I expect the gradient vector to be rotated by $120^\circ;$ this gives a pretty good reason for there being no other points on all three such surfaces near the known line.